# Excel - Selecting Rows from a list of values

Tags: excel, select, excel-formula

I have searched for an answer both on Stack and google but can't find a solution to my problem.

I have a spreadsheet containing 500 rows of data. Each row has a unique column identifier in terms of a Key Value (0, 1, 2, 3..etc).

I have a list of unique column identifiers in a .txt file that I want to select in the excel data.

I am wondering if there is a quick way I can select these rows in Excel without having to select each one manually using the select filter check-boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the filtering capabilities using something like that :

providing your .txt file contains only one value and that the column to filter is the column A

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub filterBasedOnTxt()

  Dim curWS As Worksheet
  Dim buildArray As Variant
  Dim in_line, w_txtArray, mysep As String

  Set curWS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  Open "c:\temp\myKeys.txt" For Input As #1

  Do Until EOF(1)
     Input #1, in_line
     w_txtArray = w_txtArray & mysep & in_line
     mysep = ";"
  Loop

  Close #1

  buildArray = Split(w_txtArray, mysep, -1)

  With curWS
     .Rows("1:1").Select
     Selection.AutoFilter
     .Range("A:A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=buildArray, _    
     Operator:=xlFilterValues
  End With
  set curws = nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The txt file contains a list of values for example: 1,5,6,7,15,36,47,57...

I am looking to select just the rows that match these values. So, for example, column A in excel contains a unique reference. Any rows that contain the unique reference listed in the .txt would be shown.

Comment: The sample provided assumed that the list of value in your .txt file was 1 key  per record. If all the concerned values are on the first line, this is event better... Just read the file once and use the "Split" function to create the array , use the coma(,) instead of the mysep variable. I posted a revised code based on this...

Comment: Dan I would just like to point out I have tried the code mentioned above even with a list of values and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: OK, cool. But note that this works because you use a coma (,) as separator of your list of value, and when doing a input#1, coma is interpreted as a "variable separator"...

Comment: Dan based on your above comment my list in my .txt was separated by having values on individual lines (no (,) present). Guess this still works fine for these type scenarios?